In some Android mobiles, the keyboard opens multiple times when I open the app using the deep link
When I open the app using a deep link and then click the mobile back button, the keyboard opens and closes.
When I open the app using a deep link and then click the mobile back button, the keyboard opens and closes. This issue occurs only on a particular device, not on all devices. It specifically happens when I use gesture navigation bar settings for the mobile back button, causing the keyboard to open and close unexpectedly.
